# Debuging advice for featured image option (add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'))

Tags: wordpress

The featured image meta-box does not show up on any post/page/custom-post.

On wp-admin, adding or modifying a post/page/custom-post, the meta-box for the featured-image is absent, even if the option to display the meta-box is checked. All other options work properly (when checked, meta-box appears, when unchecked, meta-box disappears).

Problem is present on dev and production environments.

Disabled all plugins and no change.

Similar code works fine on similar website I'm also working on.

Here the relevant code:

```
<?php

namespace Rezosante\Setup;

class Base {
    public static function init() {
        add_action('after_setup_theme', ['Rezosante\\Setup\\Base', 'enableThemeFeatures']);
    }

    public static function enableThemeFeatures() {
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    }
}
```

And then on functions.php:

```
Rezosante\Setup\Base::init();
```

I would expect the meta-box for the featured image to appear when the option is checked, but it does not.

I might be missing something quite obvious, as the same code works fine on another project.

Any advice/ideas on what else I could check would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems you have an extra `}` in your `init()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I had deleted the non relevant code and this } had stayed behind. I have corrected the question.